# Bokeh server datatable renders no records from Oracle sql output (incl. panda transforms)

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, bokeh

I have code that creates a bokeh datatable from an oracle sql query converted into a dataframe `df`. The original query result looks like this:

```
User | Entry | feature1 | feature2
jim    JAN       1           22
jones  JAN       1           93
ted    FEB       0           93
```

I want to return the count of `Entry` for each `User` only. Then I want to sum entries for each user in a column called 'YEARLY_TOTAL' So I do:

```
del df['feature1']
del df['feature2']
df=df.pivot_table(index=['User'], columns=['Entry'], aggfunct=len)
df=df.reset_index()
df['YEARLY_TOTAL']=df.sum(axis=1)
source=ColumnDataSource(data=dict())
```

Now it looks like:

```
User     JAN    FEB      YEARLY_TOTAL
jim    1                    1
jones  1                    1
ted           1             1
```

I attempt to render it in a bokeh server datatable with adjustable slider via:

```
def update():
    current=df[(df["YEARLY_TOTAL"]>=slider.value[0]) & (df["YEARLY_TOTAL"]<=slider.value[1])]
    source.data={
        'User': current.User,
        'January':current.Jan,
        'February':current.Feb,
        'Total':current.YEARLY_TOTAL,}

slider=RangeSlider(title="Yearly Total", start=0, end=1000000, value=(0,5000), step=10000)
slider.on_change('value', lambda attr, old, new: update())

columns=[TableColumn(field="User", title="User"),
    TableColumn(field="Jan", title="January"), 
    TableColumn(field="Feb", title="February"),
    TableColumn(field="Total", title="Total")]

data_table=DataTable(source=source, columns=columns, width=800)

controls=widgetbox(slider)
table=widgetbox(data_table)

curdoc().add_root(row(controls, table))

update()
```

The table renders in the browser, but there is no data in the table. Interestingly enough, if I save the pivoted dataframe to csv, and pass the csv to render the table (after commenting out the pandas transformations as they are no longer necessary), the datatable renders fine. What is happening?

Answer (score 0):

In the oracle sql, I made a date transformation that ended up appending spaces to the end of `'Jan'` and `'Feb'`. I won't make the same mistake again!